# Removed id_rsa file accidentally

Tags: ssh, data-recovery

I accidentally removed the `id_rsa` file from my `.ssh` directory. Now I cannot establish a connection to my remote server. However, I still have the `known_hosts` file and other files on `.ssh`. My first question is: can I recover the `id_rsa` file in any way and establish a connection with the remote server?

Now when I try to create a new RSA key pair, the message says that the key is saved in `id_rsa` but the `id_rsa` file does not appear on the `.ssh` directory. My second question is: why is the `id_rsa` file not reappearing when I create a new RSA key pair? Do I have to create the `id_rsa` file manually first?

Comment: Restore from backup. A new key would not give you access to the server (it's expecting the old key).

Comment: How is the filesystem formatted? If it is `ext2/3/4`, you may try a tool like `extundelete`. Although, since you have already started modifying the file system, it is very unlikely you can still salvage data ... First rule of data revocery: "Unmount the filesystem and don't modify it in any way other than with a recovery tool". And make a low-level backup first, if feasible.

Comment: @Kusalananda I do not have any backups. So, I need to create a new key pair and reestablish the connection. Can I do that?

Comment: Start making regular backups of your data, unless it can be recreated from elsewhere.